# How to use FileUpload widget in jupyter lab?

Tags: python, file-upload, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want to use the `FileUpload` widget in jupyter lab.
I have the following lines of code in my notebook cell:

```
uploader = widgets.FileUpload()
uploader
```

In jupyter notebook, the output of the cell is a clickable button that I can use to upload a file. In jupyter lab, the output is the following :

```
FileUpload(value={}, description='Upload')
```

Here's the info on the `uploader` object :

```
Type:           FileUpload
String form:    FileUpload(value={}, description='Upload')
File:           ~/miniconda3/envs/fastai2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_upload.py
```

Is it possible to make this widget work on jupyter lab? And if so how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using jupyterlab out the box, it doesn't have ipywidgets enabled by default, you need to rebuild it after enabling the extension. Follow the steps from [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2083#issuecomment-427094922):

1. Install [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en)
2. `pip install ipywidgets`
3. `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`
4. `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`
5. (may need to restart your lab)

It says that newer Jupyterlab has it enabled, but I still had troubles with it, depending on the platform. Manual install is usually the way to go.

Comment: I think the step I was missing was step 3 or 4, after following your instructions, everything worked perfectly. Thank you !

Comment: @StatisticDean, yeah, it is understandably not obvious, because usually installing a module is sufficient. It's not the case with JupyterLab, though. Every time you install an extension or update to it, it requires the rebuild.

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked after

```
pip install jupyterlab-widgets
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Also see

https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager

Usage

```
from ipywidgets import FileUpload
from IPython.display import display
upload = FileUpload(accept='.txt', multiple=True)
display(upload)
```

---

```
with open('z_merged_output.txt', 'wb') as output_file: 
    for uploaded_filename in upload.value:
        content = upload.value[uploaded_filename]['content']   
        output_file.write(content)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got `ipywidgets` installed you may need to update it:

```
pip install -U ipywidgets
```

And then install the newer version's files:

```
jupyter nbextension install --py widgetsnbextension
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked after running the below code

```
!jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
!jupyter nbextension enable fileupload --user --py
(doesnot require restarting of kernel)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).